# Time conversion confusions in C#

Tags: c#, timezone, utc

I'm accessing the file.LastWriteTime of a driver (.sys file) in C#. 
Code as follows:

```
DateTime fileDate = FileInfo(path).LastWriteTime;
String locaZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local.DisplayName;
DateTime BinaryDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConverTimetoUtc(fileDate, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

I checked the Drivers folder in System32 - file time is 9/27/2012 12:40:42 AM
and the local timezone is Pacific.

> Hence, fileDate = 9/27/2012 12:40:42 AM
>
> But, BinaryDate (after conversion to UTC) = 9/27/2012 07:40:42 AM

Can anyone please guide what's wrong here - seems like conversion is not happening correctly.

Ideally, we should observe BinaryDate value to be > 9/27/2012 12:40:42 AM (including DayLight Saving)

Comment: Pacific is GMT-7:00. So if you convert your local time to UTC, that should be 7 hours later. Or what is it you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just call `FileInfo(path).LastWriteTimeUtc` ?

Comment: No, UTC does not change according to daylight savings time.